# How to open a pop up window and refresh the page that opened it when the pop up is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the latest and greatest version of jQuery.

When this button is clicked:

```
<input id="ShowImages" class="" type="button" value="images">
```

This function:

```
$("#ShowImages").click(function() {
    $("#MusicianImagesDiv").load("MusicianImages.cfm?MusicianID="+MusicianID);
});
```

Loads a page into this div:

```
<div id="MusicianImagesDiv" class=""></div>
```

In that div, when this button is clicked:

```
<input id="MusicianImageUploader" type="button" value="launch image uploader">
```

This function pops up a window:

```
$("#MusicianImageUploader").click(function() {
    MyURL = "GlobalAdmin/MusicianUploader.cfm?MusicianID=" + MusicianID;
    window.open (MyURL, "mywindow","location=0");
});
```

When the "close window" button in the pop up window is pressed:

```
<input id="CloseButton" type="button" value="close this window">
```

I want to reload A SPECIFIC DIV // not the parent page

```
$('#CloseButton').click(function() {
    // to be clear, this code is in the pop up window
    // the MusicianImagesDiv div is in the parent window
    $("#MusicianImagesDiv").load("MusicianImages.cfm?MusicianID="+MusicianID);
});
```

And then close the pop up window.

Everything works perfectly except for reloading the div when the close button is clicked.

What am I doing wrong? Why does the close button not tell reload the div?

Here's the tweaked code that works flawlessly!!!

```
$('#CloseButton').click(function() {
    var MusicianID = $("#MusicianID").val();
    var LoadPage = "GlobalAdmin/MusicianImages.cfm?MusicianID=" + MusicianID;
    window.opener.$("#MusicianImagesDiv").load(LoadPage);
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: It wont work - as the closebutton is on a different page - different window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried accessing `window.opener` ? This gives you access to the parent window. So roughly the code would be

```
$('#CloseButton').click(function() {
    window.opener.$("#MusicianImagesDiv")
                 .load("MusicianImages.cfm? MusicianID="+MusicianID);
});
```

Comment: Dood, your code ROCKS!!! This worked absolutely perfectly. Thanks for being awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work - because the #closebutton is on a different window / html page - why does it need to be a new window that is opened - why can you not use a JQueryUI dialog ? that way everything is in the same page and the event will be handled

Comment: I got that answer that I was looking for.  Thanks for trying.